# Get all images from a specific directory and use it with vegas.js slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Sorry

I have completely no clue of js/jquery, so please forgive me for this question :/

## General

All files, including images, are on client side.

## What was done

I use [vegas.js](https://vegas.jaysalvat.com/) to have a very simple slideshow. Therefore i do

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vegas.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vegas.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').vegas({
        slides: [
            {   src: 'img/1.jpg'},
            {   src: 'img/2.jpg'},
            {   src: 'img/3.jpg'},
        ]
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

## What i want to do

Since i have a large image base i would like to automate declaring the `src` of all images. I thought about something like this:

```
slides: [
    for i in img/*
        {    src: i},
]
```

Could you help me out.

Comment: JQuery Javascript is client side executed, so i suppose your image will be on server and you need a server-side language (like javascript with Nodejs, PHP or Java) to generate those links.

Comment: Images are on userside

Comment: For security reason, you can't read the user side HDD with Javascript